# Angular input password autofill not working on Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

In my angular app login page, password auto fill does not work on iOS browsers. It works fine on Desktop browsers (manual typing or autofill through extension) and in mobile browsers it works when I type username and password. But not when I autofill them. Here is the list of browsers in which it does not work

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Mobileiron Web browser

Surprisingly it works on Safari. See the [StackBlitz example](https://angular-6fvpky.stackblitz.io/) for details